# Как подключить SDK к уже существующему проекту в Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Открыл программу java в Intellij IDEA, но вверху выскочила надпись "SDK проекта не найдена", что делать в такой ситуации?[image: картинка с предупреждением об отсутствии SDK]

Comment: Там рядом должна быть кнопка `Fix changes` или что то в этом роде.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно добавить путь до Java SDK
Можно так.
Правой кнопкой на проекте, вызываем контекстное меню, далее
`Open Module Settings -> Project -> New/Edit` путь до папки с Java.
У мена например на Win10 такой: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2`

[image: Скриншот1]

[image: Скриншот2]

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @НиколайСеменов если ответ решил вашу проблему, то примите его, нажав на галочку рядом с ним